# Drupal6: hook_menu_alter still having an effect after the module is disabled

Tags: caching, menu, drupal-6, hook

For some reason, the "Create content" menu item was displaying for Anon, even though there was nothing in that tree or at that path. (Anon can only create a certain type of content, but that has been moved to its own top-level navigation item.)

To solve this, I used hook_menu_alter():

```
/**
 * Remove "create content" from the menu if the user is anon
 */
function odp_menu_alter(&$items){
    global $user;
    if ($user->uid == 0) {
      unset($items['node/add']);
    } 
}
```

For some reason, this also influenced the superuser account. I disabled the module with that code. Now the **Create Content** link is back, but it leads to this error:

`Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in modules\system\system.module on line 626`

All the subtree links that were below **Create Content** still work.

I've flushed all the caches. What is happening?

Answer (score 0):

What other third party modules do you have running? Sounds like there is a code bug somewhere, but that is awfully difficult to diagnose from here.

I would try posting on the Drupal issue queue.